# Is it okay to return a large string from a C# function - would the returned value end up on the call stack?

Tags: c#, string, callstack

I am deciding whether it is better to modify an incoming parameter or to return a large string. Are there implications to returning a large string from a C# function?

Comment: Returns are almost always the right thing to do and making aliased parameters is almost always the wrong thing to do. But let's dig into your scenario a bit more. You say a "large" string, but you don't say how large "large" is to you.  A thousand characters? A hundred thousand? A million? A hundred million? What's the application?

Comment: I completely agree, but an newer to c# coming form C++ where wouldn't return something that large unless it was a pointer. 300K - 5M would be typical. I am uploading a binary file (data backup) from an app in Xamarin.

Comment: See, that's why I ask questions like that. Under no circumstances should you be storing a large binary blob in a string for uploading it. There are much better ways to solve that problem. What you've done here is called an "XY problem". You have a problem, you have a wrong idea of how to solve it, and now you're asking a question about the wrong idea. Post a question asking what the best way is to upload a large binary blob in Xamarin, if that's the problem you face!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C# strings are immutable, and are stored in the heap, not the stack (more accurately, they're reference types, so you don't need to worry about it).